# Is there any class in flutter which will work same like Handler?

Tags: java, android, flutter

Can anyone tell, what is equivalent to handler in flutter?. i want to implement a splash screen which will last for 5 seconds and after another screen will be shown.

Comment: For splash screens, I like to use the accepted answer with a `Future.wait` and another future that loads the required data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is something similar to a `Handler` class, but you can just use `Future.delayed` and in `build()` render a different UI depending on `showSplash`:

```
showSplash = true;

new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  setState(() => showSplash = false);  
});
```

Comment: Could we also have used simple `Timer` to achieve same result? If yes, then is there any downside of using `Timer` instead of using `Future.delayed(...)`

Comment: I don't think there is much of a difference. I prefer `Future` because it's used all over the place anyway. No need to consider a different API.

Answer (score 2):

### **Handler.postDelayed()** -- Used to do work after some specific time

We can either use `Future.postDelayed` (as answered by Günter) or we can use `Timer` class too.

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
 // 5 seconds have past, you can do your work
}
```

### **Handler.post()** -- Used to keep on doing work after some specific interval

We can use `Timer.periodic` function for this like

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (_) {
  // this code runs after every 5 second. Good to use for Stopwatches
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()),
      (Route route) => false);
});
```

where `NewScreen` is the screen you wish to show, it will show a new screen.